can we say "the fan turned off by itself"?
Britannica says

2 turn off (something) or turn (something) off : to stop the
operation or flow of (something) by pressing a button, moving a
switch, etc.
She turned off the alarm/heat/lights/water.
Should I leave the TV on or turn it off?

Because it says "turn off (something)", it means "something" can be omitted and that phrase can be intransitive (a verb without an object).
However, the dictionary does not have any examples using "turn off" as an transitive verb.
Other dictionaries mostly say it as a transitive verb.
I have a tiny fan and it has been on for several hours when suddenly it stopped working for some unknown reason.
I asked my daughter "the fan turned off by itself?"
But I think "go off" can be more suitable "the fan went off by itself?"
can we say "the fan turned off" or "the fan turned off by itself"?

In dictionary definitions the bracketed words cannot be omitted. But they are bracketed to differentiate them from the primary word/words being defined. They are also provided to assist you with the correct forms of the expression. Here it shows you (if you're talking about a fan) that you can say "I turned off the fan" or "I turned the fan off".  But you can't leave out the word fan.

"turned off by itself" (or "turned itself off") to me suggests that it had e.g. a timer that made it stop. If it broke, you would say "the fan stopped working", "the fan broke", etc.

We find lots of entries when we Google turned off by itself. This usage is hence quite common.
This is true too when it comes to books.  Google Books has lots of hits for turned off by itself.
For example, the chandelier turned off by itself.
Yes, we can say "the fan turned off" or "the fan turned off by itself”.
